# ¿Cómo eliminar los datos columna_tipo cuando elimino un objeto tipo de una forma correcta en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Estoy utilizando Laravel 9 y entre las entidades que estoy utilizando se encuentran "Tipo" y "Columna" que tienen una relación N a N. Esto último implica que existe una tabla "columna_tipo" que vincula a ambos.

Las columnas no se pueden eliminar, no obstante, los Tipos sí se pueden eliminar. Me gustaría saber cuál es la forma "linda" y "correcta" de llevarlo a cabo.

Actualmente tengo esto en la entidad Tipo.

```
public static function boot() 
{
    parent::boot();
    static::deleting(function($tipo){
        $tipo->servicios()->get()->each(function($servicio){
            $servicio->delete();
        });
        $tipo->columnas()->get()->each(function($columna){
            $columna->delete();
        });
    });
}
```

Interpreto que eso elimina las columnas y yo necesito que elimine las relaciones, no las columnas.

Vuestra ayuda me evitará tener que utilizar lo siguiente:

```
DB::delete('DELETE FROM columna_tipo WHERE tipo_id = :tipo_id', ['tipo_id' => $tipo->id]);
```

Comment: Puedes usar la función `detach()` que tiene laravel la cual elimina las relaciones de las tablas many to many. Podrías hacerlo de la  siguiente `$tipo->servicios()->detach();` [Mas Informacion](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso tiene buen aspecto, a diference de hacer el delete directamente. Lo voy a probar y te digo algo.